# Datalist not working in Safari

Tags: html, safari, html-datalist

I made a simple auto suggest box using data list. It does not work in Safari. Is there any work around to it.

```
<input list="places" placeholder="Enter origin airport" />
<datalist id="places">
    <option value="Manchester Ringway Interantional">
    <option value="Chicago O'Hare Intl">
    <option value="Glasgow International">
    <option value="Edinburgh">
    <option value="Dubai International">
    <option value="New York JFK">
</datalist>
```

I will be using only these 6 airports. Is there any way to implement it so it works in Safari browser?

Comment: https://github.com/thgreasi/datalist-polyfill

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Safari [does not support](http://caniuse.com/datalist) `datalist`. You could use [jQuery UI Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) Instead. The code will be something like :

```
$(function() {
  var availableTags = [
  "ActionScript",
  "AppleScript",
  "Asp",
  ];
  $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
    source: availableTags
  });
});
```

where `#tags` is the ID of your input element and `availableTags` the list of elements you need.

Comment: I tried that i get this error in the console
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'autocomplete' flight_eta.html:39
(anonymous function) flight_eta.html:39
c jquery.js:3048
p.fireWith jquery.js:3160
x.extend.ready jquery.js:433
q

Comment: There's the code of the example on the page I linked in my answer

Comment: Yes yes i added that script src already even then i get the same error @RRikesh

Answer (score 1):

you can try [Select2 Plugin](http://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/), it works with

```
IE 8+
Chrome 8+
Firefox 10+
Safari 3+
Opera 10.6+
```