# HTML5 datalist tag is not working as expected in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, safari, datalist

I have a datalist tag which allows my users to have a suggestion box. Now i know that this feature is not supported in safari. So what can i do to solve this issue?

Here is my code - I'm actually populating my values with database dynamically..

```
<select id="select_departure_city"style="border-radius:6px" onchange="this.nextElementSibling.value = $('#select_departure_city option:selected').text().trim()"></select>
<input id="input_departure_city" class="form-control admin-input width-80 height-34p padding-0" name="departure_city" type="text" list="listDepartureCity" />
<datalist id="listDepartureCity" ></datalist>
```

Before posting this i tired many solutions but none of them is worked for me.
I tired

1. [HTML5 datalist tag is not populating in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27494084/html5-datalist-tag-is-not-populating-in-safari)
2. [Datalist not working in Safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18187019/datalist-not-working-in-safari)
3. [GitHub Help1](https://github.com/Fyrd/purejs-datalist-polyfill)
4. [GitHub Help2](https://github.com/thgreasi/datalist-polyfill)

As in these posts, **Select** tag with in datalist tag is solution like this.

```
<datalist id="languages">
<select>
  <option value="JavaScript">JavaScript</option>
  <option value="Haskell">Haskell</option>
</select></datalist>
```

But in my case **Options** tag are not place within **select** tag after populating dynamically. My code after adding select is as below

```
<datalist id="listDepartureCity">
     <select></select>
     <option value="JavaScript">JavaScript</option>
     <option value="Haskell">Haskell</option>
</datalist>
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: the problem you got in safari is not about those options not inside the select tag, which, in fact you can easily append options into select. safari just dont handle well with dymanic changing datalist options.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use a feature that's not widely supported by all browsers, chances are you'll need a polyfill.  Here's one for datalist that might work for you: https://github.com/thgreasi/datalist-polyfill

Comment: i try this but not worked for me. As in our case all the options tags are not place with in the select tag as i mention in the post.